# How to start a new website project in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

I'm really beginner to `codeigniter` I'm working on CI since last 2 weeks. During this period I have created many views.php files, some controllers.php files and some models.php files

**Now I want start a new website project.**

What should I do. Should I delete all files of my controllers, views and models, etc., and download another `codeigniter` and start from the beginning?

Comment: CI has one of the best [user guides](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/) available for any PHP framework. There's no excuse to not read and reread it and soak in how beautiful it truly is.

Comment: can you please provide me a link of answer of my question from CI's user guide.

Comment: It's in my comment linked as [user guides](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Phil Sturgeon's article on how to do multiple site on one CI instance, in here he explains 2 ways of doing it and describes pros and cons.

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter

But in his latest articles he has told what happened to modular separation.

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/03/modular-separation-codeigniter-2

Answer (score 6):

You should check the documentation of codeigniter for help but just to give you a quick start ill explain how to create your first codeigniter project.

Installation
1 Download the codeigniter framework from http://ellislab.com/codeigniter
2 upload it in root directory of your website or local apache server directory.

Creating your codeigniter project.
In codeigniter your controller will handle the url requests and load appropriate model and views. So the first step is to create your controller.

1 Creating your controller: go to Applications->controllers and there you will find a built in controller called welcome.php. 
This controller loads a view welcome_message.php which is inside Application->views.
You can use this controller or create your own.
To create your own controller create a new php file myfirstcontroller.php and extend a class with same name from CI_Controller.
Note that the name of the file and your class name should be the same. the index function is the default function that will be called when you make a request to the controller

```
class myfirstcontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){

    $this->load->view("myfirstview");

    }

}
```

so when you request this controller through yoursite/index.php/myfirstcontroller

it will load a view called myfirstview.php which will reside inside applications->views.

Go ahead and create this file in applications ->views.

2 To pass data from controller to view you will send an array to the view

```
class myfirstcontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){

    $data['name']="My first application.";
    $this->load->view("myfirstview",$data);

    }

}
```

3 You can access this variable in view

```
  echo $name
```

and it will output your variable

3 you use models you have to create a file inside applications->models and call it from controller and it will return the result in the form of array.

You can look at the documentation for further help.

Hope this helped you to get started with codeigniter.

The user guide is inside your download library.

You can also view it in http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Good luck!!!